# Method\Function encryption in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I'm primarily MS SQL Server user.

Designing a PostgreSQL database, I wanted to encrypt methods\functions.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/encryption-options.html) about encryption.

Comment: Can you provide the MS SQL equivalent?  I suspect the Oracle version is a `wrapped` package.  Please confirm.